# sklearn: cannot import name 'indexable' from 'sklearn.utils

Tags: python, scikit-learn, importerror

I am trying to import train_test_split from sklearn.model_selection using the following code

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
```

However, in doing so I am receiving the following error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'indexable' from 'sklearn.utils' (D:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\__init__.py)
```

Does anybody know how to fix this import error with sklearn?

Comment: Works for me. What version of sklearn do you have installed?

Comment: Works for me in 0.21.x What's your sklearn version? (You should have posted that in the question)